# How to put an Image in an specific button of a button array?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

hi I am pretty new to java. I need to make a game name Ratsuk witch is pretty much like chess but it only has the knight. So when the knight no longer has space to move the player loses.

I did a array of buttons for this

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tablero {

    private JButton[][] mesa;

    public Tablero() {
        mesa = new JButton[8][8];
    }

    public void cuadriculado(JFrame ventana) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8, 4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < mesa.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mesa[0].length; j++) {
                mesa[i][j] = new JButton();
                mesa[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                panel.add(mesa[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < mesa.length; r++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < mesa[0].length; t++) {
                if (r % 2 == 0 || r == 0) {
                    if (t % 2 == 0 || t == 0) {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    } else {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (t % 2 == 0 || t == 0) {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ventana.setContentPane(panel);
        ventana.setSize(500, 500);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        Icon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redKnight.gif"));
        mesa[0][0] = new JButton(image);
    }
}
```

The file compiles but the image I am trying to set in the button mesa[0][0] does not appear. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create new `JButton` for `mesa[0][0]` *again*. But should set the `icon` for that existing `JButton` object.

```
Icon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redKnight.gif"));
mesa[0][0].setIcon(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  try {
Icon image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("redKnight.gif"));      
mesa[0][0] = new JButton();
    mesa[0][0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(image ));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new `JButton` object instead of adding the image to the existing `JButton` object, so the problem exists.

Setting `mesa[0][0]=new JButton(image)` will not make already added `JButton` object to the `JFrame` to be replaced. You should refresh the fundamentals of Java once.

Use `JButton#setIcon(Icon img)` method to add image to the already existing `JButton` object.

```
           `mesa[0][0].setIcon(image);`
```

And also since, you are adding the image after setting the frame visible, you may have to refresh your frame by calling `JFrame#repaint()` or so...

Or change your code like this instead:

```
    Icon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redKnight.gif"));
    mesa[0][0].setIcon(image);
    ventana.setContentPane(panel);
    ventana.setSize(500, 500);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
```